# Name of a javelin-creating gauntlet

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, dnd-3e, product-identification

I once read about this gauntlet (preatty sure it was only one, not a pair) which was able to create an enchanted javelin , or a similar shaped throwing weapon, that you could throw right away. Can you point me to the right sourcebook?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Magic Item Compendium* has the *gloves of endless javelins* on page 194 which produces a *+1 javelin* made of magical force at will, so you can attack, well, endlessly with these.

Comment: Thanks! you saved me a lot of searching around. as soon as one of us can double check for the page i'll accept the answer ^^ !